# What's the opposite action of “rounding a number”?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

Looking this up on Merriam-Webster these are the only definitions to, *unround*

> 1: to pronounce (a sound) without lip rounding or with decreased lip
> rounding 2: to spread (the lips) laterally

I'm putting together a mobile application that is gesture based (Tap to Round). Looking for a word that appropriately fits the opposite action.

Example of action:

> > [image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because choosing names for things in software is off-topic according to our Help Center.

Comment: Obviously, the opposite of "rounding" a number is "squaring" the number!

Comment: @tchrist: If "linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts" are not interested in human-centered design and nomenclature, then can you migrate the question to a different place? The question is a good one.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

*Unround* is the the opposite of *round*.

Here's what the OED has to say, along with two examples of its use unrelated to phonetics (one of which is specifically related to number rounding):

> **unround**, *v.*
> *transitive*. To make (something) no longer round. In later use *spec.* (in *Phonetics*): to reduce or eliminate the rounding of the lips when enunciating (a sound, esp. a vowel).
>  <sub>1648   H.
> HEXHAM *Groot Woorden-boeck*   *Ontronden*, to vnround, or Take
> away the roundnesse of any thing.</sub>
>  <sub>1974   *Philos.
> Trans.* (Royal Soc.) A. 276 241   We can *unround the data*,
> adding a random fraction of ±0.5 to all measurements quoted to the
> nearest foot.</sub>
>  <sub>Source: [Oxford English
> Dictionary](https://oed.com/) (login required)</sub>

If that doesn't ease your mind, you could try *Tap to Restore Decimal*. But to the (perhaps non-mathmatical) user needing this app, *Tap to Unround* is much less daunting. *Do/Undo*. *Round/Unround*. Keep it simple.

Answer (score 5):

There isn't one. You either round or don't round. If you don't round, then it means you retain the original figure or result of the calculation.

Comment: Any suggestions for my particular case? Updated my original question for applying the word.

Comment: @CarlEdwards TerryM is right.  So the answer would be a toggle:  "round? YES/NO" or you could off a choice:  "To the nearest 1/5/10/...."

Comment: Actually, Don't Round.

Answer (score 4):

There is no opposite to rounding. A rounded number contains no information that allows anyone to recover the original. Nothing may be recovered from a rounded 3 except perhaps that the original value was between 3.5 and 2.5. The only to alternative to rounding is therefore to do nothing.

Nevertheless, if you mean that the user has an option to *refine* or *alter* the amount to their own choice, you might use:

> *fine-tune* = to make very small changes to something in order to make it work as well as possible
>
> [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fine-tune)

> *refine* = If something such as a process, theory, or machine is refined, it is improved by having small changes made to it.
>
> [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/refine)

Comment: I like *refine*.  Not sure *fine-tune* fits though.

Comment: I regret the closure of this question. It is not focused on the mathematical technicalities of rounding but on the proper use of English to describe such matters. We sometimes dwell at length on some trivial literary and grammatical points but my impression is that we too often see questions with a technical flavour dismissed.

Comment: The first paragraph of this answer explains well why the OP cannot expect to find an established term for the opposite of rounding. I don't, however, think that what the OP has in mind is that 'the user has an option to refine or alter the amount to their own choice'. As I understand what the OP is doing, the rounding and the opposite of it are merely changes in what the software **displays**: rounding reduces the number of the decimals that are displayed, and the opposite operation displays additional decimals on the basis of the data that the software has had in its memory all along.

Comment: @jsw29 you may be correct. Difficult to know because not all algorithms are reversible or have memory built in. I admit to some doubt in understanding the question, which is why in my second paragraph I say “if”.